# Unable to set log level in a Java web start application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, java-web-start, java.util.logging

### Some logging levels appear to be broke?

I run a Java web start (which I will begin to call **JWS** from now on) application straight from a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 instance. The client has a static logger like so:

```
private final static Logger LOGGER;
static {
    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    // Not sure how one externalize this setting or even if we want to:
    LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINER);
}
```

In the main method, I begin my logic with some simple testing of the logging feature:

```
alert("isLoggable() INFO? " + LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.INFO));     // Prints TRUE!
alert("isLoggable() FINE? " + LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE));     // ..TRUE
alert("isLoggable() FINER? " + LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINER));   // ..TRUE
alert("isLoggable() FINEST? " + LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)); // ..FALSE
```

My alert methods will display a `JOptionPane` dialog box for "true GUI logging". Anyways, you see the printouts in my comments I added to the code snippet. As expected, the logger is enabled for levels *INFO*, *FINE* and *FINER* but not *FINEST*.

After my alert methods, I type:

```
// Info
LOGGER.info("Level.INFO");
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Level.INFO");

// Fine
LOGGER.fine("Level.FINE");
LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "Level.FINE");

// Finer
LOGGER.finer("Level.FINER");
LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, "Level.FINER");
LOGGER.entering("", "Level.FINER", args); // <-- Uses Level.FINER!

// Finest
LOGGER.finest("Level.FINEST");
LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Level.FINEST");
```

I go to my Java console and click on the tab "Advanced", then I tick "Enable logging". Okay let's start the application. Guess what happens? **Only Level.INFO prints!** Here's my proof (look at the bottom):

[image]

I've done my best to google for log files on my computer and see if not Level.FINE and Level.FINER end up somewhere on the file system. However, I cannot find the log messages anywhere.

### Summary of Questions

1. Why does it appear that logging of `Level.FINE` and `Level.FINER` does not work in the example provided?
2. I set the logging level in my static initializing block, but I'd sure like to externalize this setting to a configuration file of some sort, perhaps packaged together with the EAR file I deploy on GlassFish. Or why not manually write in some property in the JNLP file we download from the server. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I should add that I'm quite new to the whole logging concept, so if you feel you have any valuable knowledge to share in the context of Java web start and Java EE and/or GlassFish, please do share!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual data that can be copied instead.  *"I've done my best to google"*  Note that Google does not index text in images (one of the many reasons text is preferable).

Comment: Yeah I understand you. But I did write in text what I expected and what I got. So the picture was redundant, or more of a mean to provide a graphical context for anyone [human] who perhaps didn't even know that you can connect a console to the JWS application. But thank you for sharing your thoughts Andrew! What made you find this question?

Comment: I have registered an interest in [tag:java-web-start] questions and this post has the tag.  Now you mention it, you missed the [tag:java] tag which almost certainly has more followers than all the other tag combined.

Comment: Oh I see you added that tag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution for problem no 1.

After doing a little bit more reading on the topic, I concluded that a logger in Java uses a handler to publish his logs. And this handler in his turn has his own set of "walls" for what levels he handles. But this handler need not be attached directly to our logger! You see loggers are `organized in a hierarchical namespace` and a child logger `may inherit` his parents handlers. If so, then `By default a Logger will log any output messages to its parent's handlers, and so on recursively up the tree` (see [Java Logging Overview - Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html)).

I ain't saying I get the full picture just yet, and I sure didn't find any quotes about how all of this relates to a Java Web Start application. Surely there has to be some differences. Anyways, I did manage to write together this static initializing block that solves my immediate problem:

```
static {
    LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    /*
     * This logic can be externalized. See the next solution!
     */
    // DEPRECATED: LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINER);
    if (LOGGER.getUseParentHandlers())
        LOGGER.getParent().getHandlers()[0].setLevel(Level.FINER);
    else
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINER);
}
```

### Solution for problem no 2.

The [LogManager API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) provided much needed information for the following solution. In a subdirectory of your JRE installation, there is a subdirectory called "lib" and in there you shall find a "logging.properties" file. This is the full path to my file on my Windows machine:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\logging.properties`

In here you can change a lot of flavors. One cool thing you could do is to change the global logging level. In my file, this was done on *row 29* (why do we see only a dot in front of the "level"? The root-parent of all loggers is called ""!). That will produce a hole lot of output; on my machine I received about one thousand log messages per second. Thus changing the global level isn't even plausible enough to be considered an option. Instead, add a new row where you specify the level of your logger. In my case, I added this row:

`martinandersson.com.malivechat.app.App.level = FINER`

However, chances are you still won't see any results. In solution no 1, I talked about how loggers are connected to handlers. The default handler is specified in *logging.properties*, most likely on *row 18*. Here's how my line reads:

`handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`

Also previously, I talked about how these handlers in their turn use levels for what should trouble their mind. So, find the line that reads something like this (should now be on *row 44*?):

`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO`

..and in my case I swapped "INFO" to "FINER". Problem solved.

### But!

My original inquiry into this matter still hasn't provided an answer how one can set these properties closer in par with the application deployment. More specifically, I would like to attach these properties in a separate file, bundled with the application EAR file I deploy on GlassFish or something like that. Do you have more information? Please share!